# Android dynamic linear layout containing edit box and spinner

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I have below layout i.e 1 spinner and a linear layout containing some edit box's and spinner's.this layout maps/represent to an object (Lets call it X).
The main spinner will be having n number of entries and each entry maps to the layout object (X).So, In all i will need to have n number of layouts
I want to allow user to fill only 1 object at a time ,so, I would keep only 1 layout visible.In order to solve this , One way would be having n number of layouts in .xml and playing with the visibility in onitemselected of the listener.Is there any other better/optiomized way of solving this.
How can i make this dynamic i.e if i dont know the value of n initially ?

```
`<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/linesspinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linename1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/linecffiltext" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/trospinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/Tro_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/linetrotext" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/line1troval"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cfspinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/cf_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/linecffiltext" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/line1cfval"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, put that LinearLayout in another xml and call that xml as many times you want inside loop.
sample xml, name attrib_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lable"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:textColor="#000033" />
</Linearlayout>
```

code to call that in loop

```
 Linearlayout row11 = (Linearlayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.attrib_row, null);
        ((TextView) row11.findViewById(R.id.lable)).setText("example");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.With the above method ,The linear layout is not visible on screen.I tried row11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); also.